# How to delete integer record from text file in java?

Tags: java, file-io, text-files

I have a simple problem ... i write this code to delete a record that starts with a string but when tried to apply this code to delete another record that starts with an integer it gives me an error

here is my code:

```
public void deleteSupplier(String company) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    File inputFile = new File("C:\\Users\\فاطمة\\Downloads\\suppliers.txt"); // Your file  
    File tempFile = new File("C:\\Users\\فاطمة\\Downloads\\suppliers2.txt"); // temp file

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

    String currentLine;

    while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        if(currentLine.contains(company))
            continue;

        writer.write(currentLine);
        writer.newLine();
    }

    writer.close();
    reader.close();

    File inputFile1 = new File("C:\\Users\\فاطمة\\Downloads\\suppliers.txt"); // Your file  

    File tempFile1 = new File("C:\\Users\\فاطمة\\Downloads\\suppliers2.txt"); // temp file

    inputFile1.delete();
    boolean successful = tempFile1.renameTo(inputFile1);

    if(successful == true)
        System.out.println("Supplier deleted successfully");

    else if(successful == false)
        System.out.println("Error: deleting failed, supplier might not be found.");
}
```

for example i have a record like this:

```
   Hamada Port 111
   Hobeee Jack 447
```

the code works well for this but when tried to apply code for a record like this

```
   1 Hamada 147
   7 Hobeee 444
```

it gives me error.

note: i used:

```
   int id
```

instead of

```
   String company
```

and use id instead of company in the function:

```
        currentLine.contains(id);
```

but it gives error.

some help please?

Comment: When you get an error, it usually helps when you tell which error.

Comment: error tells me that function contains cannot convert character to integer

Comment: Don't use `int id`. While you may think that something like `123` is a number, the computer sees it as 3 characters (that happen to be digits). The code that uses `String` works for all cases, you don't need to switch it to anything.

Comment: I must use int id, this function takes an integer value that search for it in the text file then delete all the line that starts with this integer value

Comment: Then convert the int to a String inside the method.

Comment: So this is my question:how to convert integer to string ??

Comment: Your name sure is accurate. You can use `String.valueOf(yourInt)`. I also recommend reading the [tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/), otherwise you will be having a hard time doing anything correctly.

Comment: hahahaha funny joke but thanks i just forget it.... but there is a new problem i convert int id to string by adding this code

                  `String i = String.valueOf(id);`

and use i instead in function contains but when running this code it deletes all the records in the file ... why ?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `startsWith()` and not `contains()`?

Comment: And finally it works .... thanks to you very very much @Kayaman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are calling 'contains' method of String class, you can only give an instance of child classes of CharSequence as a parameter like String for example (as you did for your string case). Since Integer is not a subclass of CharSequence interface, you have to convert it before applying to 'contains' method. Converting int value to String will be the way to go.

```
currentLine.contains(company)
```

Comment: well, i convert int to string by adding this code:



           `String i = Integer.toString(id);`



but when running this code it deletes all records